# How to edit action when click add button in credit note invoice odoo

Tags: odoo

When I click the add button, the original invoice and credit note invoice change to auto payment and paid invoice.I want to add some change when click add button.But I founf only it in payment_view.xml. How can I add some modification when click add button.[image]

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @kerbrose. In my image, there is add button in outstanding debits.When I click this button, this invoice will be auto payment.So I want to know is where is the function of this add button? I need to override this funtion.

Comment: That's a special widget and not changeable/extendable by normal xml views. You have to look into the JavaScript Code.

Comment: why would like to override it. tell us what are you actually trying to add??

Comment: @kerbrose. I create invoice in 1/10/2020 and make create note invoice that date is 12/10/2020. When I click add button in create note invoice, their payment date is switch.Payment date of credit note invoice is 1/10/2020 and original invoice payment date is 12/10/2020.That why i want to override and change payment date.

Comment: @CZoellner.Can I know a little reference for this?